# How to disable ForceDark in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, statusbar

I've been making an app in flutter and testing it on my and my friends phones. It works fine everywhere except one phone, status bar keeps being black. As I understand this is because he has forcedark mode on his phone. (I've been trying changing status bar using SystemChrome and package:flutter_statusbarcolor/flutter_statusbarcolor.dart') None of this helped. Is it possible to disable ForceDark in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like SystemChrome and this package are not always working correctly.

I now use `AnnotatedRegion` with `SystemUIOverlay` value and everything works nice.